# Errno 101 Network is unreachable on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, telegram

I know there are many threads but how telegram works has changed and most of the solutions doesn't work. I've searched before posting here!
I'm using a virtualenv and Flask, i'm pretty sure that i've set all correctly but when i try to send a message it gives me this error:

```
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /botMYBOTID/sendMessage (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f13cd74b3d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))
```

I copied just the last part of the error,
Here is my code:

```
bot = telepot.Bot("MYBOTID") #py anywhere prova
canaleProva3= -100123456789

app = Flask(__name__)

def main():
    print("ciccia")

@app.route('/', methods=['POST','GET'])
def webhook():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        bot.sendMessage(canaleProva3, "prova")
        return Response('post', status=200)
    else:
        return Response('get', status=200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Do I need a paid account to resolve this? I wanted to try my bot before pay. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: **Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable** seems like a solid error.

Comment: if i go to https://mysite.eu.pythonanywhere.com everything works fine (i can see the homepage)  so i don't know why it gives me error with telegram

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this: https://github.com/lstil/pythonanywhere-telegram-bot/ I resolved, basically i just had to add this line:

```
telepot.api.set_proxy('http://proxy.server:3128')
```

Comment: More explanation on that can be found on [PythonAnywhere help pages](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/403ForbiddenError/)